# Дописать недостающие числа в массив и проверить в foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Как можно дописать недостающие числа в массив и в foreach определить что это число было дописано в массив?

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 10, 11);
foreach ($numbers as $number){
    if(){
        echo $number.'<br />';
    }else{
        echo 'Число было дописано: '.$number.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: тут проще через for, если я правильно понял задачу. должно получится 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так, если я вас правильно понял
Но в следующий раз предлагайте свою наработку или пишите что у вас не получилось. За вас никто и ничего делать не будет.

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 10, 11);

for( $i = 1; $i <= 11; ++$i ) {
    if( !in_array($i, $numbers) ){
        $numbers[] = $i;
        echo 'Число было дописано: '.$i.'<br />';

    }else{
        echo $i.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то похожее)
Попробую использовать ваш вариант.

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 10, 11);

// уже результат с заполненными значениями
$filledArray = range($numbers[0], end($numbers));
// тут массив с теми значениями, которыми было произведено заполнение
$diffArray = array_diff($filledArray, $numbers);
```